# Symfony-cmf Routing

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-cmf

I have read all of the routing inside symfony cmf and I don't get it. 
Could someone provide me how does it goes to the for example SimpleController. 
I get that this is a generic controller when i press on the dynamic or static and when I press on the other menu item then ContentController is generic controller.

For example I have built my own bundle and I want to change how those the routing goes.
I want to hardcode it. So I know how to build it from web interface.
Providing me with some documentation would be cool also ? :)

Comment: sorry, but i fail to understand what exactly you are asking. do you want to map some dynamic routes to a specific controller? or do you want to change the generic controller for a different one? can you please explain in more detail what you want?

Comment: I want to change generic controller to a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/reference/configuration/routing.html#default-controller

You can set defaults just like you can with the standard routing.